# How to access multiple image objects in a loop, from outside of the loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-imaging-library

```
from PIl import Image, ImageFilter
import os

img_path = "some_location"

for image in os.listdir(img_path):
    img = Image.open(image)
    new_img = img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

In for loop there are many instances of new_img. Is there a way to save them temporarily or use them from memory to iterate over another loop. I don't want to save them in storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them into a list. Something like:

```
images = []
for image in os.listdir(img_path):
    img = Image.open(image)
    new_img = img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    images.append(new_img)

for new_img in images:
    # Loop over and use them here
```

You could also make the first loop a comprehension:

```
images = [Image.open(image).filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
          for image in os.listdir(img_path)]
```

Although that first line is getting a little noisy.

---

If you don't want all of `images` in memory at once, you can do lazy-processing using generators. I'd use either a generator function:

```
def produced_images():
    for image in os.listdir(img_path):
        img = Image.open(image)
        yield img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)  # yield images as they're needed

for new_img in produced_images():
    # Use here
```

Or, just a generator expression:

```
images = (Image.open(image).filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
          for image in os.listdir(img_path))

for new_img in images:
    # Use here
```

Comment: Excellent point about memory consumption. Let's hope people read it, learn and use generators more often.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ya, I realized after that by "storage", they may have meant not wanting everything in memory at once (I originally assumed they were referring to the disk). Unfortunately though of course, lazy ways will only work if they only need access to each image once. But ya, I love generators.